# llvm/Support/TargetRegistry.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have this error when I `make` project in WSL(Ubuntu 20.04). And I have installed LLVM and Clang.Hou should I do?

````
Kconfig  Makefile  README.md  build  configs  include  resource  scripts  src  tools
why@YOGA:~/ics2021/nemu$ make
+ CXX src/utils/disasm.cc
src/utils/disasm.cc:5:10: fatal error: llvm/Support/TargetRegistry.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include "llvm/Support/TargetRegistry.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/home/why/ics2021/nemu/scripts/build.mk:40: /home/why/ics2021/nemu/build/obj-riscv32-nemu-interpreter/src/utils/disasm.o] Error 1```
````

Comment: Decide a package name for file = `TargetRegistry.h` : **1**. `apt-file search TargetRegistry.h` .... **2**. On-line search https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=TargetRegistry.h .... and https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=impish&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=TargetRegistry.h

Comment: Thanks! I have solved it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: can you explain how you solved the error? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually, It's part of the NJU ICS Course project, and the right path should be `#include "llvm/MC/TargetRegistry.h"`. For llvm-11, the file is in "llvm/Support/TargetRegistry.h". But for llvm-14, it's in "llvm/MC/TargetRegistry.h". You should check where the `TargetRegistry.h` is. For me with Ubuntu, the file is at `/usr/include/llvm/MC/`.

Comment: It's true, and I've found and solved it . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to continue the pa0, just install llvm11 by `apt-get install llvm-11` then follow the PA0 Guide to change the `nemu/src/utils/filelist.mk`